# On dimensions as a concept

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, spacetime-dimensions

really naive question here, i don't know anything about physics, in a professional sense.

Light is a electromagnetic wave, and itself requires 3 dimensions to propagate, then how can a one-dimensional or 2 dimensional being even perceive anything ?

AND

If the existence of these lower " dimensions " are questionable , how do we know higher dimensiions exist ?  Are we sure we are correct in conceptualizing the concept of dimensions , maybe its something else entirely...?

Comment: *a one-dimensional or 2 dimensional being* These don’t exist. All living things are three-dimensional. Even an atom is three-dimensional.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I squeeze something really hard, will it ever become two-dimensional?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136754/)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE. (1) Waves propagate in however many spatial dimensions there are. (2) We don't know hidden dimensions exist, but there's ongoing research into models such as string theory which, whatever their benefits elsewhere in physics, would necessitate such dimensions ([or would they?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-critical_string_theory))

Comment: @Ghoster i see these videos where people give examples of these beings to explain concept of dimensions... and i just couldn't get it how that should work,so i thought to ask it here.... basically i wanted like a proof that the dimension as a concept or a physical thing , can exist or atleast makes sense

Comment: It sounds like you're getting distracted by [what would happen in spacetime of a given dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropic_principle#Dimensions_of_spacetime) rather than focusing on [how spacetime could have that dimension](https://mathoverflow.net/q/25983).

Comment: well, since any transverse wave requires atleast 2 dimensions, and as i am speaking of light waves explicitly, so i atleast think 1 dimensional world won't have lights, and since light must have a perpendicular magnetic field to the electric field, both of them transverse, so i just don't see how 2 dimensional world can actually perceive light....                        and if there are inconsistencies in concepts of lower dimensions i am having a hard time thinking about higher dimensions